# Are Maruts sons of Sindhu or Pṛśni?

Tags: rig-veda, maruts

Rig Veda [X.78.6](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe32/sbe3254.htm) says that Maruts are sons of Sindhu.

> These noble ***sons of Sindhu***  are like grinding-stones, they are always
>   like Soma-stones , tearing everything to pieces; these sons of a good
>   mother are like playful children, they are by their glare like a great
>   troop on its march.

Rig Veda [6.66.3](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv06066.htm) says that Maruts are the sons of Pṛśni.

> They who are Sons of the rain-pouring Rudra, whom the long-lasting One
>   had power to foster: The Mighty Ones whose germ great ***Mother Pṛśni*** is
>   known to have received for man's advantage.

Can anyone explain reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had discussed this issue with friend, who is a Vedic Scholar.  His explanation is as follows:

> **Prshni** means that which ***sprinkles/rains*** (=raincloud, =fertility).  Maruts are the tempests that bring the rain of this rain cloud to earth. Who bring fertility and positive change to the ground.
>   As they roar and are terrible, they are often called sons of Rudra.
>
> As rain cloud is nothing but the evaporated water of stream (samānam
>   etad udakam) (Sindhu) they might be called the **sons of Sindhu**.
>
> They may also be called the Rudras.  They are the Rudras when Indra
>   Marutvā becomes formidable as the Rudra

Max Müller in his explanation to [Rig Veda X.78.6 (Note 1)](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe32/sbe3254.htm#an_10:78:6:1) says as follows:

> Síndhu-mâtarah may be a synonym of Prisni-mâtarah, sindhu being used
>   as a name of the water in the sky. It may also mean, having the river
>   Sindhu for their mother, i. e. coming from the region of the river.

Comment: Though this is not a completely unsourced answer, however It would be more useful if you cite some authentic sources.